# How to iterate over a 2D array with a single loop?

Tags: java

how can we navigate through the two dimensional array without using nested loops.i.e by using only one loop.

```
 String ar[][]=new  String [3][4];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a hint:

```
int i = 9;
System.out.println(i / 4);  // 2
System.out.println(i % 4);  // 1
```

Comment: thanks....got it,i would have to use % and / operator to access element indexes and run the loop 12(no of elements i.e no of rows*no of column) number of times.

Comment: Nice hint, good solution. But I'm still not so sure why you couldn't just nest two loops.

Comment: what would you like to achieve by iterating 2D array by one loop? bcz number of iteration would be same either you use one loop or 2 loops.

Comment: when using something like openmp, the ability to make something parallel only would work on the outer loop, thus a solution like this is very helpful